# snprintf + Pebble

Tags: c, sizeof, strlen, printf, pebble-sdk

I'm developing for Pebble and I'm off to a rough start.

I'm trying to populate a text_layer with 2 strings and 2 values, something like this:

> WAIT AVG: 3 MAX: 5

Since `malloc` is not supported in Pebble SDK, I can't use `sprintf`, hence I'm stuck with `snprintf`. The following code only prints "4":

```
srand(time(NULL));
int average = (rand()%6)+1; 
int maximum = average + 2;
static char *avgText="WAIT AVG: ";
static char *maxText="MAX: ";
snprintf(labelText,sizeof(avgText) + sizeof(average) + sizeof(maxText) + sizeof(maximum),"%s %d %s %d",avgText,average,maxText,maximum);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know that I can create 4 separate TextLayers but that's kind of a last resort for me.

Comment: Why does `sprintf` depend on `malloc`?

Comment: @CoryNelson has a point, snprintf only takes an extra param `n` to prevent buffer overflows, as `n` is max buffer capacity to fill

Comment: @Siidheesh That's just overly verbose. `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` by the standard.

Comment: @CoryNelson, it is redundant here, but it's useful to include `sizeof(the type used)` in case he migrates to a wide char type :), not sure if the Pebble SDK supports wide chars though

Comment: @CoryNelson - I guess they initially omitted `sprintf` to avoid bloat, and then relented and added `snprintf` on the dubious premise of avoiding buffer ovverruns. Which it doesn't! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275381/strncpy-vs-sprintf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're just using `snprintf` wrong. ;-)

The second parameter (which you're trying to calculate, badly) is the length of the character array that you're printing into, *not* the number of characters you're trying to write.

Something like this should work:

```
char labelText[64]; // Is this big enough?
snprintf(labelText, 64,"%s %d %s %d",avgText,average,maxText,maximum);
```

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(avgText)` and `sizeof(maxText)` are sizes of pointers, not array sizes. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672162). Change your code to

```
static char avgText[] = "WAIT AVG: ";
static char maxText[] = "MAX: ";
```

in order to make them arrays.

edit:

Further note, that `sizeof(average)` is the size in bytes `average` covers internally, *not* how many bytes a decimal representation would consume.

edit2:

As Roddy's answer says, it's wrong to calculate the size we *want* to have and pass that size to `snprintf` as an actual buffer size. We can, however, calculate the size we want to have provided there is a reasonable upper bound (e.g. with 32 bit `int`, 10 bytes (without 0-terminator) are always sufficient, but maybe you can give a lower upper bound in your use case):

```
char labelText [
        sizeof avgText - 1 + 10 +
        sizeof maxText - 1 + 10 + 3 + 1
];
/* sizeof avgText counts the 0-terminator, so does sizeof maxText, hence
the -1, two times 10 for the `int` (or any reasonable upper bound you have),
3 spaces and the 0-terminator. */
```

and you could even use `sprintf`. With `snprintf`, you can do:

```
snprintf(labelText, sizeof labelText,"%s %d %s %d", avgText, average, maxText, maximum);
```

HTH

Comment: You don't need to do this: There's no need to calculate the output string length at run-time.

Comment: @Roddy: Where did I say so?

Comment: @maifso. My point is there's no need to do the (faulty) calculation that the OP is attempting. The no. of characters to be output is not important, but the size of the buffer *is*. (Ignore 'at runtime' in my earlier comment)

Comment: Yes, I've seen your answer in the meanwhile. Wait a minute, I'll edit soon.

Answer (score 1):

read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) of `snprintf()` properly. it says, the second argument `size` is used to refer to the `number of bytes` to be written.

`sizeof (avgText)` and `sizeof(maxText)`is not gonna work here. It refers to the size of the `pointer`, not the `length` of the array it holds. Maybe you want to use `strlen()` for the string length.

Answer (score 0):

So this worked:

```
srand(time(NULL));
static char labelText[]="WAIT AVG: xxxxx MAX: xxxxxx";
int average = (rand()%6)+1; 
int maximum = average + 2;
static char avgText[]="WAIT AVG: ";
static char maxText[]="MAX: ";
snprintf(labelText,sizeof(labelText),"%s %d %s %d",avgText,average,maxText,maximum);
text_layer_set_text(waitField,labelText);
```

thanks guys